# what is difference between _lwsync and _sync_synchronize in AIX environment?

Tags: c, synchronization, aix

It seems _lwsync is synchronizing multiple processors and

_sync_synchronize is synchronizing in all threads using memory barriers.

But I want to know more specific about differences.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

__lwsync:

The lwsync barrier is broadly similar to
sync, including cumulativity properties, except that does not
order store/load pairs and it is cheaper to execute; it suffices to guarantee SC behaviour in MP+lwsyncs (MP with
lwsync in each thread), WRC+lwsync+addr (WRC with
lwsync on Thread 1 and an address dependency on Thread
2), and ISA2+lwsync+data+addr, while SB+lwsyncs and
IRIW+lwsyncs are still allowed.

__sync_synchronize:

This function synchronizes data in all threads.
A full memory barrier is created when this function is invoked.It is a atomic builtin for full memory barrier.No memory operand will be moved across the operation, either forward or backward. Further, instructions will be issued as necessary to prevent the processor from speculating loads across the operation and from queuing stores after the operation.